# What are the odds my building will be flooded?

Tags: probability

The US Geological Survey defines a [100-year flood plain](http://water.usgs.gov/edu/100yearflood.html) plain as a place that has a 1% chance of flooding in any given year.

Suppose I build a building in such a flood plain and I expect that building to have a 50-year lifespan.

What are the odds my building will be flooded at least once during its 50-year life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{Probability of getting flooded at least once}=1-\text{Probability of never getting flooded}$$
$$\text{Probability of not getting flooded in a given year}=0.99$$
$$\text{Probability of not getting flooded in fifty years}=(0.99)^{50}$$
$$\text{Probability of getting flooded at least once}=1-(0.99)^{50}\approx40.50\%$$